Issue with combining __declspec(property) with operator[]
I don't understand why in this C++ program the [0] and [19] in (b.a_test)[0][12][19] get ignored, while on the next line they aren't.
Could anyone exlpain to me why?
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    A operator[](int i) {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
        return *this;
    }

};

class B {
public: 
    A* a;
    A get_a() {
        return *a;
    }

    __declspec(property(get = get_a)) A a_test;;

    B(A* a_) {
        a = a_;
    }
};


int main() {
    B b = B(new A());
    (b.a_test)[0][12][19]; // output 19 while it should oupout 0 12 19
    (b.get_a())[0][12][19]; //output 0 12 19 as expected

    delete b.a;
    return 0;
}

I was expecting the program to output this :
12
19
0
12
19

but the output was:
19
0
12
19


Side note : please do not do this __declspec(property(get = get_a)) A a_test;; anything with __ is not going to be "standard C++" just accept that in C++ you have to create a getter function. Also make sure your example compiles, which it doesnt : https://godbolt.org/z/hbPcYerxx

I had to replace the compiler extension __declspec(property(get = get_a)) A a_test;; with standard C++ to get it to compile.  It worked on my machine.  Maybe you are using that compiler extension incorrectly.

@PepijnKramer take a look at the tags before posting comments.

@Eljay You too take a look at the tags before posting comments. The code compiles well by msvc.

Using Matt Godbolt's Compiler Explorer, I was able to get the code to work by doing: static_cast<A&&>(b.a_test)[0][12][19];.  That avoids the compiler extensions parsing rules from discarding the [0][12].

@3CxEZiVlQ I did  see visual studio tag, but I still would advice not to use extensions. C++ has idioms (and "properties" are just not part of that). Using "standard C++" will help with getting help too

@PepijnKramer "make sure your example compiles, which it doesnt" - no, you did not see the tag and showed the clang errors.

@MinxinYu-MSFT the method provided by Eljay is working but the point of __declspec(property) is to be convenient but having to write static_cast<A&&> is more annoying than just using a get method

@EliottMartin I added an answer.

As  Eljay
said, use  static_cast to   avoid the compiler extensions parsing rules from discarding the [0][12]
Or
use pointer works:
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A operator[](int i) {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
        return *this;
    }

};

class B
{
public:
    A* a;
    A* get_a () {
        return a;
    }

    __declspec(property(get = get_a)) A* a_test;

    B (A* a_) {
        a = a_;
    }
};


int main () {
    B b = B (new A ());
    (*b.a_test)[0][12][19]; 

    delete b.a;
    return 0;
}



I agree that using pointers works, but it kinda reduce the point of using a property in the first place.
However i was more looking for and explanation rather than a fix (as the fix is a bit obvious)

Unfortunately, this is not standard C++.   There is only reference document:  MSDN, and the documentation doesn't explain it. You can report this to the developer community, and post link here so that we can follow.  It may be a bug.
